# using a Websocket page from the local Machine

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm working on an applicatioin that I want to use with websocket interaction.  I've used a node.js and socket.io based server and simple chat page as a starter for my page.  I'm making modifications and figuring out the interactions between the server and html page.

The person who wrote the basic chat page used inline javascript on the html page as the client side of the chat, so I've broken that out into its own javascript file, no big deal there.

The issue is that I want to use the html and associated javascript file from the local machine, to connect to the node.js server I'm creating on the web-server.  His setup was accessing the html page on the web-server in the same folder as the server.js file that acted as the web-socket server.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the client side javascript file to start doing it's thing when the page is opened (i'm guessing an on load event is needed), and how to set it up to call to the webserver javascript file.

I'm going to post his code here, it's not mine, I just used his tutorial to make the chat.html and server.js.  Basically copy and paste.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated as always.

-----------------chat.html--------------------------

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
            console.log("Connecting to " + URL);
            var socket = io.connect(URL);
            // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
                socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
            });
            // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
            socket.on('updatechat', function(username, data) {
                $('#conversation').append('<b>' + username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
            });
            // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
            socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
                $('#users').empty();
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
                });
            });
            // on load of page
            $(function() {
                // when the client clicks SEND
                $('#datasend').click(function() {
                    var message = $('#data').val();
                    $('#data').val('');
                    // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
                    socket.emit('sendchat', message);
                });
                // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
                $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
                    if (e.which == 13) {
                        $(this).blur();
                        $('#datasend').focus().click();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
        <div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
            <b>USERS</b>
            <div id="users"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
            <div id="conversation"></div>
            <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
            <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---------------------server.js-----------------------------

```
var port = 5000;
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

console.log("Listening on port " + port);
server.listen(port);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameter
        io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's actually a really nice sample. read the code :)

Comment: I appreciate you pushing me, and I've mad some modifications. I have the javascript originally in the html now on the server, and the script tag pointing to it, I get the console.log 'Connecting to URL' part, but it errors on the socket.io saying io is undefined line 6, where I try 'var socket=io.connect(URL);'.  I can't figure out where to refer to the socket.io/socket.io.js from the remote client...  Any thoughts on that?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: on client you need the port in your `var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + ":" + 5000;`